# Windows 8 kernel debugging over VirtualBox host-only network

Tags: debugging, windows-8, kernel, virtualbox

My setup is: Windows 7 host system, VirtualBox/Windows 8 32-bit target system (debugee), host-only network to connect the two. Starting with Windows 8 it's declared possible to setup kernel debugging over network --- seems to be a nice option in this case. So I verified that the NIC is supported (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh830880 --- Intel 822540 DevID 100E is included on the list) and followed instructions in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh439346(v=vs.85).aspx. Not successfull, windbg says: debuggee not connected, can't break the target system. (There is some communication since windbg detects target system restart.)

So the question is: has anyone tried this? Succeeded? Anything important that I miss? Should I resort to configure a serial connection or perhaps install VirtualKD?

Comment: Have you temporarily disabled the firewall on both your host and guest to ensure there are not some ports being inadvertently blocked? Great question BTW.

Comment: Yes, both firewalls are disabled.

Comment: Helo @KrzysztofCzarnowski did you fix this?